# Pandas: how to merge different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

The first dataframe contain the name of people:

```
df1  NAME
0    Paul
1    Jack
2    Anna
3    Tom
4    Eva
```

and a second name with the information of the amount of money received and payed by each person. There are some person that are not in `df1`, for instance `Zack`. Some people could not appear in the list, for instance `Tom`

```
df2  Receiver Payer Amount  
0     Paul    Jack   300 
1     Anna    Paul   600
2     Anna    Eva    100
3     Eva     Zack   400
```

I want to create a dataframe with all the amount of money received and payed by each people. So:

```
df3  NAME   RECEIVED  PAYED
0    Paul     300      600
1    Jack      0       300
2    Anna     700       0
3    Tom      NaN      NaN
4    Eva      400      100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df3 = (df1.join(df2.melt('Amount', value_name='NAME', var_name='type')
                   .groupby(['NAME','type'])['Amount']
                   .sum()
                   .unstack(fill_value=0), on='NAME'))
print (df3)
   NAME  Payer  Receiver
0  Paul  600.0     300.0
1  Jack  300.0       0.0
2  Anna    0.0     700.0
3   Tom    NaN       NaN
4   Eva  100.0     400.0
```

**Explanation**:

1. First reshape DataFrame by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)
2. Aggregate `sum` per each `NAME` and `type`
3. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for columns by second level of `MultiIndex`
4. Last left [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to first `DataFrame`

---

Another solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df3 = (df1.join(df2.melt('Amount', value_name='NAME', var_name='type')
                   .pivot_table(index='NAME', 
                                columns='type', 
                                values='Amount', 
                                aggfunc='sum',
                                fill_value=0), on='NAME'))
print (df3)
   NAME  Payer  Receiver
0  Paul  600.0     300.0
1  Jack  300.0       0.0
2  Anna    0.0     700.0
3   Tom    NaN       NaN
4   Eva  100.0     400.0
```

Last if necessary `rename` columns:

```
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'Receiver':'RECEIVED','Payer':'PAYED'})
print (df3)
   NAME  PAYED  RECEIVED
0  Paul  600.0     300.0
1  Jack  300.0       0.0
2  Anna    0.0     700.0
3   Tom    NaN       NaN
4   Eva  100.0     400.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df2.melt('Amount', value_name='NAME', var_name='type'))

   Amount      type  NAME
0     300  Receiver  Paul
1     600  Receiver  Anna
2     100  Receiver  Anna
3     400  Receiver   Eva
4     300     Payer  Jack
5     600     Payer  Paul
6     100     Payer   Eva
7     400     Payer  Zack
```

Comment: I received an error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'melt'`

Comment: @emax - It is lower pandas version problem, change `df2.melt('Amount', value_name='NAME', var_name='type')` to `pd.melt(df2, 'Amount', value_name='NAME', var_name='type')`

Comment: @jazreal great, thanks. I receive the same error for the `group_by`. Should I solve that in the same way?

Comment: @emax - Do you think `groupby` ? Instead `group_by`, it seems typo.

Comment: @jazreal yes it was a typo, sorry. However in the `groupby` line I have this error: `TypeError: unhashable type: list`

Comment: @emax - What is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: @jazreal `0.18.0`

Comment: @emax - It is not very old, it should working. What about `print (df.dtypes)` ? Maybe some data related problem.

Comment: @emax - If second solution with `pivot_table` raise same error, problem should be in data.

Comment: in `df2` all of them are `int64` except for amount that is `float64`. in `df1` the name is  `int64`

Comment: So data are OK, not some another typo? `print (pd.melt.melt(df2, 'Amount', value_name='NAME', var_name='type').groupby(['NAME','type'])['Amount'].sum())` still raise error?

Comment: I just realised in comment above is double `melt` ;) But if remove it like `print (pd.melt(df2, 'Amount', value_name='NAME', var_name='type').groupby(['NAME','type'])['Amount'].sum())`, still problem with groupby?

Comment: Or melt problem with `print (pd.melt(df2, 'Amount', value_name='NAME', var_name='type'))` ?

Comment: @jazreal `melt` works while keeping the `groupby` I still get the same error :-(

Comment: I have no idea, 2 possible solutions - upgrade pandas to last or try another pivot_table solution `df3 = (df1.join(df2.melt('Amount', value_name='NAME', var_name='type')
                   .pivot_table(index='NAME', 
                                columns='type', 
                                values='Amount', 
                                aggfunc='sum',
                                fill_value=0), on='NAME'))`

Comment: @jazreal just tried the second method and it works. GREAT!